# What's wrong with this dereferencing statement?

Tags: c

I have this in an exercise with pointers:

```
char *str = "Hello";
int count = 0;
int len = 5;
printf("%c\n", *(str + count));
printf("%c\n", *(str + len - count - 1));
*(str + count) = *(str + len - count - 1);
```

Both `*(str + count)` and `*(str + len - count - 1)` are valid values as the `printf`s attest (I get `H` and `o`). So why do I get a `bus error` when I run the above?

Comment: What is the size of the `char` array and what are the values of `count` and `len`?

Comment: As you increment `count`, one reference will move one direction and the other the other.  I'm guessing you're walking off the end of your array, possibly off the front end.

Comment: Edited with a more complete code example.

Comment: So many times this has been asked before: https://www.google.com/search?q=segmentation+fault+writing+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` points to a string literal which resides in memory where it is undefined behaviour to write to. Many times the compiler will put these string literals into memory with permissions that do not include write-permissions. This is why you're crashing.

Change it to this:

```
char str[] = "Hello";
```

This will create an array on the stack and initialise it with the C-string `"Hello"`; since it resides on the stack, you can freely modify it.

Comment: Any idea why is it a `bus error` and not just *segmentation fault*?

Comment: @kaoD nope, no idea. Writing to string literals is Undefined Behaviour though, so absolutely anything could happen, including bus errors or the atmosphere exploding.

Comment: Then I'm totally writing an infinite fork-and-crash loop... and watch the world burn! ;)